# Passing $index as argument of $emit breaks function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, angularjs-ng-repeat, parameter-passing

I have a list of forum threads (topics), when the user mouses over each one I want it's metadata to be displayed in a separate panel, to identify which thread is selected I'm trying to pass `$index` as a parameter of `$emit` but this seems to break the function.

View:

```
<header ng-include="includes.header.src"></header>
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div ng-include="includes.threadList.src" id="content-left"></div>
    <div id="content-divider"></div>
    <div ng-include="includes.threadDetails.src" id="content-right"></div>
</div>
```

threadList include(where problem is occuring):

```
<ul id="threadList">
    <li ng-repeat="thread in threadList | filter:includes.header.searchQuery" ng-mouseover="$emit('updateThreadDetails', {{$index}})">  
        <a href="/#/threads" ng-click="">
        {{thread.title}}, moused over {{count}} times. This is item {{$index}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

threadDetails include:

```
<h3>{{includes.threadDetails.title}}</h3>
```

Controller:

```
function threadListCtrl($scope){
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.$on('updateThreadDetails', function(event,index) {
        $scope.count++;
        $scope.includes.threadDetails.title = index;    //$scope.threadList[index].title;
    });
    
    $scope.threadList = [
        {title: 'I like horse'},
        {title: 'I like turtle'},
        {title: 'I like actor'}
    ];
}
```

Passing a sting via `ng-mouseover="$emit('updateThreadDetails', 'myString')"` works as expected(`includes.threadDetails.title` becomes `'myString'`). Here's the healthy sample text from threadList:

```
I like horse, moused over 26 times. This is item 0
I like turtle, moused over 26 times. This is item 1
I like actor, moused over 26 times. This is item 2
```

When `{{$index}}` is passed the output becomes ill and in `'moused over x times'` x is always 0 and the thread details remain unchanged. As a workaround I tried pre-setting `{{$index}}` so I was just passing a primitive thusly though this didn't work:

```
ng-mouseover="index = '{{$index}}'; $emit('updateThreadDetails', index)"
```

Comment: Do you mean to say `ng-mouseover="index = $index; $emit('updateThreadDetails', $index)"` ? Since you're in an angular directive `{{}}` delimiters aren't required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need data binding (from the double curly braces) in the expression you pass to [ngMouseOver](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angMouseover) as Angular already expects to process it as an Angular expression (with [$interpolate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolate)).  So you can use the variable `$index` directly, like so:

```
ng-mouseover="$emit('updateThreadDetails', $index)"
```

Also, I'm assuming you also want to update the count for each item, individually.  So perhaps you would prefer:

```
$scope.count[index]++;
```

Displaying it in your html like this:

```
moused over {{count[$index]}}
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5v2Aj/1/)